# I have two web.config files. Which one should I use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, azure-sql-database

I recently built an application using visual studio express. This application was built using a local DB provided by VS express. I now have a subscription (free trial) to Microsoft Azure. What changes do I need to make to my project in order to point my project to the newly created Azure DB?

I also noticed I have 2 web.config files. one in the root directory and one in the views folder.

I believe I have to make an update to my connection string, but in a specific config file or both?

Here is my root directory web.config connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20160922101748.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20160922101748;Integrated   Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and my (views) web.config connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe only one web.config with connection strings should be enough. Keep the one in the root.

Download Azure DB connection strings from the Azure portal and replace `connectionString` values in the `web.config` file with the Azure DB connection string(s).

You might also need to whitelist your machine's IP address in the Azure Portal to allow connections to Azure DB.

Comment: Thanks. I've replaced my local connection string with the Azure portal connection string as you suggested. All pages are viewable except for the page which inserts and retrieves data from my DB (which I assume is in reference to the config file in my views folder) - I get the following error while trying to access that specific page: http://mediastream.azurewebsites.net/Movies Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: if I understand correctly, I now have 2 databases. mylocalDB which contains the table that stores entries from my web page and the Azure DB which contains my contains my entire project?

Comment: First, try to comment out the local connection string. Second, try to debug the controller's action in the page you get an exception -- the exception should contain more details about the problem you are having.  If you could post the full exception, I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the web.config on the root folder as thats the one used by the application.

And you are right, you need to point the connection string to your Azure database.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely only need to update the one web.config in the root of the application with the connection string. The other web.config in the views folder is needed for your views to use html helpers and to make routing work as you expect in an mvc application so do not remove it.